# Output exceeding terminal window height

Tags: command-line, io-redirection

I had run a program that resulted in many more lines of output than my current terminal window height. As a result, I could only see partial results...is there any way to get the full output?

I am using the bash shell.

Comment: Please change the word "width" in your question title by the word "height". Your accepted answer does not correspond to your wording with "width".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could send the output to a file:

```
$ your_command > /tmp/output.txt
```

You could then open up that file in any text editor and examine it at your leisure.

**Or,** you could pipe the output directly to a program such as `less` that is specifically designed as a text reader and can help you page through data when it is more than a screen-full:

```
$ your_command | less
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of redirection, but I was hoping if there is any way I could resuscitate my last output, fully without having to run the program again.

Comment: @Sayan There isn't, sorry.

Comment: @Sayan: You can only do that if you are running in some sort of terminal that keeps a buffer for you. If you use `tmux` (or the older `screen`) you can set them to keep hefty scroll-back buffers so that you can browse and even search the output quite a ways back ... but you have to be running in one ahead of time you can't roll back time and capture output that's already come and gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shift+Page Up/Down to scroll the current output.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to which shell you are using, we need to know which terminal app you are using, for instance Gnome-terminal, or Konsole are the 2 popular ones in Linux.  As mentioned by another answerer, SHIFT+PAGEUP is a common keystroke to scroll back through previous screens of terminal output.

P.S. When you said "terminal window width" did you mean "terminal window height?"

Comment: - definitely looks like that "height" was meant instead of "width".